# Count records matching pattern with Awk

Tags: text-processing, awk, scripting

So I was told to do `last > lastloggedin` which creates a file that shows the classes last login since the last system reboot, and now I am asked to write an Awk script which is named `myawk` that counts/determines how many lines of  `lastloggedin` contain the string `CFS264`.

I've done `grep -c CFS264 lastloggedin`

Comment: Do you have to use `awk`? If not, you could just use `grep -c CFS264 lastloggedin | wc -l`.

Comment: @Axel: `grep -c (something) (something) | wc -l` will ***always*** produce "1".

Answer (score 33, accepted):

To get you started you can use `awk` to search for lines in a file that contain a string like so:

```
$ awk '/CFS264/ { .... }' lastloggedin
```

The bits in the `{ .... }` will be the commands required to tally up the number of lines with that string. To confirm that the above is working you could use a `print $0` in there to simply print those lines that contain the search string.

```
$ awk '/CFS264/ { print $0 }' lastloggedin
```

As to the counting, if you search for "awk counter" you'll stumble upon this SO Q&A titled: [using awk to count no of records](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5114586/using-awk-to-count-no-of-records). The method shown there would suffice for what you describe:

```
$ awk '/CFS264/ {count++} END{print count}' lastloggedin
```

#### Example

```
$ last > lastloggedin

$ awk '/slm/ {count++} END {print count}' lastloggedin 
758

$ grep slm lastloggedin  | wc -l
758

$ grep -c slm lastloggedin
758
```

**NOTE:** You don't say which field CFS264 pertains to in the `last` output. Assuming it's a username then you could further restrict the `awk` command to search only that field like so:

```
$ awk '$1=="CFS264" { print $0 }' lastloggedin
```

Comment: sorry, cfs264 is part of a username. Thank you guys for taking your time to help me figure this out, i was getting quite confused and frustrated.

Comment: @TayshaunS - np, you're quite welcome, thanks for the Q and good luck with `awk`.

Answer (score 6):

The following example counts the times I am mentioned without needing the `lastloggedin` file:

```
$ last | awk '$1=="yeti" { ++count } END { print count }' 
106
```

If you insist in using or are forced to use the `lastloggedin` file, you can do it this way:

```
$ last > lastloggedin
$ awk '$1=="yeti" { ++count } END { print count }' lastloggedin
106
```

Use `$1~/some_chars/` to get all user names containig the given chars or `$1~/^prefix/` to match only names starting with `prefix`:

```
$ last | awk '$1~/et/ { ++count } END { print count }'
106
$ last | awk '$1~/^ye/ { ++count } END { print count }'
106
```

---

P.S.:

Scan `man awk` for more hints... ;-)

`awk` is very rewarding: You can do lots of stuff after a very short time of learning...

Answer (score 2):

Last can includes users logins from previous reboots. As such, the following will only print users since the last reboot:

```
last | awk 'NR==1,$1=="reboot"{if ($1 ~ /cfs264/ ) { count+=1; }}END{ print count; }'
```

The first part of the awk command specifies a range - start from the first row until the first column is 'reboot'.