# Recursively count number of files in folders in tar file

Tags: linux, awk, tar

I'm further extending a previous question to count number of files in tar file ([link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23594009/how-to-count-the-number-of-files-inside-a-tar-gz-file-without-decompressing)) to a new question on **how to count files under subfolders in a tar file**. What I would to have at the end is:

1. list the folders that contains files in it
2. count the number of files **within** that folder

My example *tar file listing* `tar -tvf myfile.tar` looks like below *(the real tar file has more files and directories)*. There are a total of 2 folders where *folder_files_1* has 3 files within and *folder_files_2* has 4 files within.

```
drwxrwxrwx someuser/users      0 2017-08-07 11:43 ./root_folder/subfolder/folder_files_1/
-rwxr-xr-x someuser/users 538962 2017-08-07 11:43 ./root_folder/subfolder/folder_files_1/i716266.MRDC.270
-rwxr-xr-x someuser/users 538962 2017-08-07 11:43 ./root_folder/subfolder/folder_files_1/i716267.MRDC.266
-rwxr-xr-x someuser/users 538944 2017-08-07 11:43 ./root_folder/subfolder/folder_files_1/i716268.MRDC.287
drwxrwxrwx someuser/users      0 2017-08-07 11:50 ./root_folder/subfolder/folder_files_2/
-rwxr-xr-x someuser/users 538696 2017-08-07 11:50 ./root_folder/subfolder/folder_files_2/i717157.MRDC.8
-rwxr-xr-x someuser/users 538694 2017-08-07 11:50 ./root_folder/subfolder/folder_files_2/i717158.MRDC.4
-rwxr-xr-x someuser/users 538692 2017-08-07 11:50 ./root_folder/subfolder/folder_files_2/i717159.MRDC.34
-rwxr-xr-x someuser/users 538696 2017-08-07 11:50 ./root_folder/subfolder/folder_files_2/i717160.MRDC.5
```

The closest solution I've searched pointed me to using `awk` after `tar` (see references [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/163271/count-records-matching-pattern-with-awk) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17908555/printing-with-sed-or-awk-a-line-following-a-matching-pattern)).

`tar tvf myfile.tar | awk '/^d/ {print $0; /$6/; getline; file_no++} END {print file_no}'`

`/$6/` is to match the corresponding folder `./root_folder/subfolder/folder_files_1/`. But it still is no accurately counting the file numbers under the *matching directory*, ie. *folder_files_1, _folder_files_2*.

Any suggestions on how to fix my code?

Comment: The same solution in your other question should work: `tar tvf myfile.tar | wc -l`

Comment: @NasirRiley No, it won't.  That will count *everything* in the tar file, now he's asking for only certain paths.

Comment: The way that he's worded it is somewhat confusing. Perhaps it can be certain that he wants to find only files but I don't see where it says that he's looking for certain paths. The answer right below this will give him what he wants if it's only files but if he only wants certain paths then it's going to get really hairy and convoluted.

Answer (score 1):

```
tar -tvf file.tar | grep '^-' | wc -l
```

This will count the number of lines in the `tar` output that start with `-` (i.e. files). Change `/^-` to `/^[^d]/` to count "anything but directories" if you have special types of files in your archive.

Another way, with `awk`:

```
tar -tvf file.tar | awk '/^-/ { n++ } END { print n }'
```

Both of these commands outputs `7`, the total number of files in the archive.

---

If you want separate counts for each subfolder:

```
tar -tvf file.tar | awk '/^d/ { d = $NF; next } { n[d]++ } END { for (d in n) print n[d], d }'
```

This generates

```
4 ./root_folder/subfolder/folder_files_2/
3 ./root_folder/subfolder/folder_files_1/
```

for the data that you have provided.

The `awk` code in this last example picks out the directory name from any line that starts with `d` and uses it as a key in an associative array. The array entry is incremented for each found file.  At the end, all entries and their count are printed.

Comment: Depending on whether pipes and device files count as "files", you might use something like `grep '^[^d]` to specifically omit directories.

Comment: Works for the data given, but `$NF` doesn't work if (path)names contain whitespace, and that logic is wrong if the tar contains e.g. `/dir/{file1,subdir/[abc],file2}`

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 I understand your note about white spaces, but I don't fully understand the comment about the logic. Are you concerned about sub-subfolders or subfolders occurring mixed in with files (I could understand that).

Comment: I think that's what @dave is talking about: files from parent directory listed after subdirectory and its files, in which case `d` should be reset or extracted from the filename.

Comment: @muru Ah. Yes. Well, in this case this is a simple solution for simple archives...

Answer (score 1):

Another option:

```
tar tf archive.tar |
    awk '
        { if (gsub("[^/]+$", "")) { h[$0]++} }
        END { for (f in h) { printf "%d\t%s\n", h[f], f } }
    '
```

The first `awk` statement strips filenames, and counts the instances of resulting directory paths. The second runs when the input has been fully consumed (i.e. at the end of *stdin*) and prints the list of paths and their respective counts.

The whole thing can be run into a single line if you prefer (just literally concatenate the whole lot). I've split it here for readability.

Result from running against your tarball:

```
4       ./root_folder/subfolder/folder_files_2/
3       ./root_folder/subfolder/folder_files_1/
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have GNU tar, it has a [`--to-command`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/tar.1.html) option:

```
--to-command=COMMAND
  Pipe extracted files to COMMAND.  The argument is the pathname
  of an external program, optionally with command line
  arguments.  The program will be invoked and the contents of
  the file being extracted supplied to it on its standard
  output.  Additional data will be supplied via the following
  environment variables:

  TAR_FILETYPE
         Type of the file. It is a single letter with the
         following meaning:

                 f           Regular file
                 d           Directory
                 l           Symbolic link
                 h           Hard link
                 b           Block device
                 c           Character device

         Currently only regular files are supported.
  ...
  TAR_FILENAME
         The name of the file.
```

These variables can be used to safely handle filenames with spaces, etc.

For example, using shell string substitution to remove the filename from the path given, then using sed to print only the paths for non-directories, you can then sort and apply `uniq -c` to get the count:

```
tar xf foo.tar --to-command 'echo "$TAR_FILETYPE" "${TAR_FILENAME%/*}"' |
  sed -n '/^[^d]/s/^. //p' | 
  sort |
  uniq -c
```

If you have GNU sed, sort and uniq, you can use their `-z` options and `printf "%s %s\0"` instead of `echo` to safely handle all filenames.

Example:

```
% tar xf dev/pacaur/byobu/byobu_5.124.orig.tar.gz --to-command 'printf "%s %s\0" "$TAR_FILETYPE" "${TAR_FILENAME%/*}"' | sed -zn '/^[^d]/s/^. //p' | sort -z | uniq -zc | tr '\0' '\n'
     15 byobu-5.124
      2 byobu-5.124/Applications/Byobu.app/Contents
      1 byobu-5.124/Applications/Byobu.app/Contents/MacOS
      8 byobu-5.124/Applications/Byobu.app/Contents/Resources
      4 byobu-5.124/etc/byobu
      3 byobu-5.124/etc/profile.d
      1 byobu-5.124/experimental
     23 byobu-5.124/po
      1 byobu-5.124/snap
     38 byobu-5.124/usr/bin
     43 byobu-5.124/usr/lib/byobu
     18 byobu-5.124/usr/lib/byobu/include
      1 byobu-5.124/usr/share/appdata
      4 byobu-5.124/usr/share/byobu/desktop
     12 byobu-5.124/usr/share/byobu/keybindings
      4 byobu-5.124/usr/share/byobu/pixmaps
      1 byobu-5.124/usr/share/byobu/pixmaps/highcontrast
     11 byobu-5.124/usr/share/byobu/profiles
      4 byobu-5.124/usr/share/byobu/status
      3 byobu-5.124/usr/share/byobu/tests
      3 byobu-5.124/usr/share/byobu/windows
      3 byobu-5.124/usr/share/dbus-1/services
      4 byobu-5.124/usr/share/doc/byobu
     37 byobu-5.124/usr/share/man/man1
      1 byobu-5.124/usr/share/sounds/byobu
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind running it twice (to get the count, then the lines), you can use grep.

For the count:

```
tar tvf myfile.tar | grep <path> | wc -l
```

For the lines, just remove the `| wc -l`

If you'd prefer to just run `tar` once, you can save the output to a file then `cat` it to grep and wc.  The script all together would look something like this:

```
tmp_file=$(mktemp)
tar tvf myfile.tar > $tmp_file
cat $tmp_file | grep <subdir> | wc -l
cat $tmp_file | grep <subdir>
rm $tmp_file
```

If you want a one-liner there's probably a hack you can do with process substitution and redirection, but if you're running this with any cadence you'll probably end up putting it in a script/alias/function anyway so this is a little easier to read and understand.

If you have multiple paths in the tar file that you'd like to grep out, you can put them all in a text file and use `grep -f <paths file>`

Comment: Thanks for your answer, however, if I have more folders and files in my .tar file, I will have to point to them each for the `grep <path>` which is not the ideal solution.

Comment: To get a count of each path that is true, but if you use the script i wrote up your overhead is minimal and each grep is relatively cheap.  You can use multiple patterns in grep.  I updated the answer to reflect this, but you can also specify multiple patterns on the command line with '-e'